# How can i solve this error? ./node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process' in

Tags: api, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm using Nextjs and I'm trying to use stripe for a subscription. The button bellow is fetching a api but i get the error bellow. I tried using /api/spripe.js instead of /test/stripe.js but is even worse (i don't even hit the api. I get 404)

[image: Browser]
[image: test/stripe.js]
[image: index.js]

**Dependencies:**
"dependencies": {
"next": "12.1.6",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-dom": "18.1.0",
"stripe": "^8.220.0"
},

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Full stripe.js https://pasteboard.co/tepfXbPBSPA4.png

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Also note that API routes in Next.js _have to_ be under the `api` folder. They can't be set anywhere else. See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I tried to use the api folder but i get a 404

Comment: Try moving the code to the `api` folder, post the updated code in snippets and add any errors you're getting.